# cakephp add multiple records to database at one time with assoceatded id form other table?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0 I am trying to add multiple images to my image table as well and add the Feature name and content to the content tbl and get the id to use in the image table. I have manage add the info i need to the feature tbl and return the id. however it will not add to the image table.  In the form i am using 'multiple' => 'multiple' on the gallery to allow the user to select more than one image for the gallery.

My issue is that it will not save my images just the feature part as noted above. I need help understanding how to save multiple image under one feature id and also to make sure that my hidden placement_id is correctly matching my images.

Thank you in advance.

Controller:

```
 public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        // parse the image file name to get a name without the ext to use for an alt tage.
        $file_name = array();
        $file = $this->request->data['Image']['image'];

        foreach ($file as $value) {
            $temp_file = ($value['name']);

            $info = pathinfo($temp_file);
            $temp_name =  basename($temp_file,'.'.$info['extension']);

            // set veriable to the array of name generated
            $file_name[] = $temp_name; 
        }

        if(!empty($this->request->data)){
            //save the featuer name and content to feature tbl and return id            
            $feature = $this->Feature->save($this->request->data);
            //debug($feature);

            if(!empty($feature)){
                //set feature_id to id returned above and added to data 
                $this->request->data['Image']['Feature_id'] = $this->Feature->id;
                debug($this->request->data);

                //set name the file_name generated above and added to data
                $this->request->data['Image']['name'] = $file_name;
                debug($this->request->data);

                $this->Feature->Image->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View/add.ctp

```
<?php   
echo $this->Form->create('Feature', array(
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
        'role' => 'form',
        'type' => 'file',
        'inputDefaults' => array(
            'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'),
            'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
            'class' => array('form-control'),
            'label' => array('class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'),
            'between' => '<div class="col-lg-6">',
            'after' => '</div>',
            'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-inline')),
        ))); ?>
<?php
    echo '<fieldset>';
    echo '<legend>Add Features</legend>';

    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">';
    echo $this->Form->input('Feature.name');    
    echo '</div></div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
    //----------------------- Image Block -----------------------------//   
    // group main image //
    echo '<fieldset>';
    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">';
    echo '<legend>Main Image</legend>';

    echo $this->Form->input(
            'Image.image.', array(              
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'class' =>'main_image')); 

    echo $this->Form->input(
            'Image.placement_id.', array(
                    'type' => 'hidden',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'class'=> 'main_image'));

    echo '</div></div>';

    // bottom left image //
    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">';
    echo '<legend>Bottom Left</legend>';
    // group image 2//
    echo $this->Form->input(
            'Image.image.', array(                  
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'class' =>'bl')); 

    echo $this->Form->input(
            'Image.placement_id.', array(          
                            'type'  => 'hidden',
                            'value' => '2',
                            'class' => 'bl'));
    echo '</div></div>';

    // bottom right //
    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">';
    echo '<legend>Bottom Right</legend>';

        echo $this->Form->input(
            'Image.image.', array(                  
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'class' =>'br')); 

    echo $this->Form->input(
            'Image.placement_id.', array(          
                            'type'    => 'hidden',
                            'value' => '3',
                            'class' => 'br'));      
    echo '</div></div>';

    //----------------------- Gallery Block -----------------------------//     
    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">';        
    echo '<legend>Gallery</legend>';
    echo '<h4><em>Uploade multiple image for the gallery once.</em></h4>';
    echo $this->Form->input(
            'Image.image.', array(                  
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple',
                    'class' =>'gallery')); 

    echo $this->Form->input(
            'Image.placement_id.', array(          
                            'type'  => 'hidden',
                            'value' => '4',
                            'class' => 'gallery'));
    echo '</div></div>';
    //----------------------- Content Block -----------------------------//     
    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">';
    echo '<legend>Content</legend>';
    echo $this->Form->textarea('Feature.content', array('rows' => '5', 'cols' => '55'));
    echo '</div></div>';

    echo '</fieldset>';
    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">';
    echo $this->Form->end('Save Content');
    echo '</div></div>';
```

Feature model:

```
<?php
class Feature extends AppModel{
    public $useTable = "features";
    public $displayField = "name";

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Image'=>array('classname' => 'Image', 'foreignkey' => 'Feature_id'),

    );
}
```

Image Model:

```
<?php
class Image extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
            'image' => array(
                'tempDir' => TMP,
                'uploadDir' => 'img/uploads/',
                'finalPath' => 'img/uploads/'
            )
        )
    );

    public $useTable = "images";
    public $displayField = "image";
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Placement' => array('classname' => 'Placement', 'foreignkey' => 'Placement_id'),
        'Wheel'     => array('classname' => 'Wheel', 'foreignkey' => 'Wheel_id'),
        'Button'    => array('classname' => 'Button', 'foreignkey' => 'Button_id'),
        'Feature'   => array('classname' => 'Feature', 'foreignkey' => 'Feature_id')

    );

    public $validate = array(
        'url' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
    );
}
```

Debug output for my 2nd if clause:

```
array(
'Feature' => array(
    'name' => 'Test1',
    'content' => 'testing',
    'id' => '254'
),
'Image' => array(
    'placement_id' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '2',
        (int) 2 => '3',
        (int) 3 => '4'
    ),
    'image' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-fp5-wheels.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/php5gK2Bb',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 323233
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-jeep-jk.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/php6AyLrN',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 318954
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-jeep-jk.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpMPyOhp',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 318954
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-fp8-afw.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpalo870',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 294194
        )
    )
)
```

)

Debug for my third if clause:

```
array(
'Feature' => array(
    'name' => 'Test1',
    'content' => 'testing'
),
'Image' => array(
    'placement_id' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '2',
        (int) 2 => '3',
        (int) 3 => '4'
    ),
    'image' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-fp5-wheels.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/php5gK2Bb',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 323233
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-jeep-jk.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/php6AyLrN',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 318954
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-jeep-jk.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpMPyOhp',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 318954
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-fp8-afw.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpalo870',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 294194
        )
    ),
    'Feature_id' => '254'
)
```

)

```
array(
'Feature' => array(
    'name' => 'Test1',
    'content' => 'testing'
),
'Image' => array(
    'placement_id' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '2',
        (int) 2 => '3',
        (int) 3 => '4'
    ),
    'image' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-fp5-wheels.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/php5gK2Bb',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 323233
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-jeep-jk.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/php6AyLrN',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 318954
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-jeep-jk.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpMPyOhp',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 318954
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'name' => 'vector-fp8-afw.png',
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpalo870',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 294194
        )
    ),
    'Feature_id' => '254',
    'name' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'vector-fp5-wheels',
        (int) 1 => 'vector-jeep-jk',
        (int) 2 => 'vector-jeep-jk',
        (int) 3 => 'vector-fp8-afw'
    )
)
```

)

Comment: could you post the debug info set in your controller (from the innermost if clause) .. also I noticed, that the image fields in your view got a trailing dot (`Image.image.`)

Comment: I have added all the debugs I have in my code. As for the dot I read a post that by adding the dot it will string the images together as an array when adding multiple images. When I remove the dot I only git the last image in my form added to the data post array.

Comment: can any one help me with this? I have been reading cakephp docs and all I truly think I am right there I just need some expert help. thank you